# How to alert a user Windows 8 phone app

Tags: windows-phone-8

I want to alert a user if they are close to a nearby point of interest in windows phone8. However I am having trouble finding help as all info I see seems to be on android. Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I hate to be that guy but here it goes... What have you tried? Where is your code? What sources have you referenced? Can you be more specific? What type of notification are you looking for? Toast notification? MessageBoxes? Inside the app or outside the app?

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone 8.1 supports the GeoFence API, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn263744 that's what you need to use to trigger an geo specific alert.

See a tutorial about Geofencing on WP 8.1 here: http://java.dzone.com/articles/geofencing-windows-phone-81